# how to make Redux state reset every time React component starts rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I have a state in redux that tells me the current number of posts that are rendered on the page

it looks like this

```js
{
  postReducer:{
    ...state,
    loaded:0,
    
  }
}
```

I have multiple components that should use this state when I switch between them.

Example:
I am on the home page all the posts from people I follow are there the state looks like this

```js
{
  postReducer:{
    ...state,
    loaded:15,
    posts: [],
    profilePosts: [],
    
  }
}
```

when I go from home to my profile or any other persons profile I want to see their posts only
but in order to start fetching their posts, the ***loaded*** state must be 0 but it's the same 15

I want the loaded to be 0 every time I go to a new component and keep its value while I am on the same component

I am using ***react-router-dom***  to switch between pages

I tried resetting it in the ***useEffect*** but the first batch of posts are the ones that are loaded only

Comment: Can you share some code? Sounds like you want to fetch on load of each page regardless of what's in redux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, what is the issue with useEffect.
I believe that you can do this in two ways:

---

Once your component loaded you can set 0 to loaded posts number:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
useEffect(() => {dispatch(cleanupPostsNumberAction)}, []);
```

---

Once your component unloaded (when you move from one page to another), you can use cleanup function to set `loaded` to 0

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
useEffect(() => () => {dispatch(cleanupPostsNumberAction)}, []);
```

So if this answer is not complete, you can provide a little bit more context on the problem you have

Comment: This worked but I want a follow-up question. does having multiple useEffects any side effects other than the useEffect code ofc?

Comment: @AhmedGaafer No additional side effects. Probably react creates more watchers under the hood, but I believe that is not something you should care about